# F# type constraints and reflection

Tags: f#

Is there any way to determine whether a given type parameter satisfies the F# comparison constraint through reflection?

I would suspect not, since the expression

```
typedefof<Set<_>>.MakeGenericType [| typeof<System.Type> |]
```

appears to yield no errors. Still, I would like to hear some authoritative opinion on this.

Comment: Isn't the comparison constraint just implemented in terms of `IComparable`? I.e., can't you just see if the type implements that interface?

Comment: Even if a generic parameter did implement `IComparable`, it doesn't necessarily mean that this was enforced by a constraint. In other words, this would have to be declared in the generic parameter constraints, which does not appear to be the case.

Comment: @eirik You are correct -- if you look at the definition of the FSharpSet<T> type with Reflector, there aren't any constraints on the generic parameter type (there should be a constraint that it implements IComparable<T>). Please report this to `fsbugs` at `microsoft.com` -- it appears to be an F# compiler bug.

Comment: @JackP. How is this a bug? Does the spec require `comparable` types to be marked with `'T :> IComparable`?

Comment: @ildjarn it's not that simple.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f-1-9-7.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting from Don Syme's thorough [post on equality and comparison constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dsyme/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f):

The constraint *type : comparison* holds if:

- if the type is a named type, then the type definition doesn't have the *NoComparison* attribute; and
- the type definition implements *System.IComparable*; and
- any “comparison dependencies” of the type also satisfy *ty<sub>i</sub> : comparison*

The constraint `'T when 'T :> IComparable` can be encoded in CIL and reflected upon, whereas neither is true of `'T when 'T : comparison`.

Since the two constraints are not equivalent, marking `comparable` types with the `IComparable` constraint is a bit misleading since it would make it impossible to distinguish between the two using reflection.

There's a similar relationship between the `equality` constraint and `IEquatable<_>`.

EDIT

Jack's mention that the `comparison` constraint could be encoded in F# metadata prompted me to look at the metadata reader in PowerPack. It can be used to detect the constraint:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata

let setEntity = FSharpAssembly.FSharpLibrary.GetEntity("Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpSet`1")
for typeArg in setEntity.GenericParameters do
  printfn "%s - comparison=%b" 
    typeArg.Name 
    (typeArg.Constraints |> Seq.exists (fun c -> c.IsComparisonConstraint))
```

Here's a contrived example that shows the disparity between implementing `IComparable` and satisfying `comparison`:

```
type A() = 
  interface IComparable with
    member __.CompareTo(_) = 0

[<NoComparison>]
type B() =
  inherit A()

type C<'T when 'T : comparison>() = class end
type D<'T when 'T :> IComparable>() = class end

let c = C<B>() //ERROR
let d = D<B>() //OK
```

Comment: The `comparable` constraint implies `IComparable`, but not the other way around (because of the additional restriction about the "comparison dependencies", which I imagine is there to support structural comparison). So I think it still makes sense that the F# compiler add the `IComparable` (or even `IComparable<T>`) constraints to the generic parameters; not doing so makes interoperating with other CLR languages error-prone -- you'll always have to make sure you *also* add those constraints yourself. And, if necessary, you could encode `comparison` constraints in the F# metadata resources.

Comment: @JackP. I think you've got it backwards.  Implementing `IComparable` implies that a type satisfies the `comparable` constraint, but not the other way around (...).

Comment: I don't see how it makes interoperating with other languages error prone. What would the error be? I don't think the spec guarantees that `'T : comparison` and `'T :> IComparable` are interchangeable.

Comment: @Daniel -- Doesn't it? The second line of the spec you quoted says that for a type to support the `comparison` constraint, it must also implement `IComparable`. In a manner of speaking, `comparison :> IComparable`. The third line is there just to support F# structural equality -- can you think of any cases where you'd need a generic parameter to support that specific condition and not just `IComparable`? I can't -- so I think it makes sense to add the `comparison` constraint to the F# metadata, and *also* encode the `IComparable` constraint in the CIL metadata.

Comment: @JackP. I agree. There's no reason I can think of not to add it. My only contention is with calling it a bug...a nice-to-have feature, perhaps.

Comment: @JackP. I added an (admittedly contrived) example demonstrating the disparity between the two. It doesn't refute your assertion, only shows that there is a difference.

Comment: +1 Really nice! It is cool this can be done using the metadata reader!

Comment: Unsurprisingly enough, this doesn't work with types defined in dynamic assemblies, hence fsi. Bummer..