# Comparing two objects with default IComparable implementation with F# Reflection

Tags: reflection, f#, icomparable

Given two objects in F#, is there a way to use their IComparable method to compare them, assuming they are both of the same sub-type and that IComparable is implemented for their common sub-type.

What I am trying to achieve in pseudo-code :

```
    let tycompare (o1 : obj) (o2 : obj) : int option =
        let (ty1, ty2) = (o1.GetType(), o2.GetType())
        if ty1 <> ty2 then
            None
        else
            if IComparable is implemented on ty1 then
                o1.CompareTo(o2) |> Some
            else
                None
```

I am aware of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329454/f-type-constraints-and-reflection) but I do not think it helps answering my question directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also write this more tersely with `Option.bind`, but this is a good fit for pattern matching.

We can define an [active pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns) for matching `IComparable`.

```
let (|IsComparable|) (obj : obj) = 
    match obj with
    | :? IComparable as comparable -> Some(comparable)
    | _ ->  None
```

F# lets you use active patterns in `let` bindings, so that the intent of function is more clearly conveyed.

```
let compare (IsComparable o1) (IsComparable o2) =        
    match (o1, o2) with
    | (Some o1, Some o2) when 
        o1.GetType() = o2.GetType() -> Some(o1.CompareTo(o2))
    | _ -> None
```

This can also be compacted (without the active-pattern - @kaefer) :

```
let compare (o1 : obj) (o2: obj) = 
    match (o1, o2 ) with
    | (:? System.IComparable as o1), (:? System.IComparable as o2) when 
        o1.GetType() = o2.GetType() -> Some(o1.CompareTo(o2))
    | _ -> None
```

Comment: You can also do without active patterns, using [`as` patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching) instead: `| :? System.IComparable as i1, (:? System.IComparable as i2) when ...`

Comment: @kaefer I've added the just pattern version. I have a definite bias for active patterns :)

Comment: Thanks Asti. It works for basic types which implement IComparable, which is what I was asking for, but it doesn't for types such as double[], string[]... I guess types which are more of the "kind" `'T when 'T : comparison`. How can we extend your solution to also cover these cases? I tried addin `| (:? Comparison<_> as c1),  (:? Comparison<_> as c2) -> ...` (without type parameters, as I won't have one) but it does not work.

Comment: What do you think should be the result of comparing a double array with another?

Comment: 1- Thanks @Asti. A simple [partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) relationship would work. In the same way that we can think of a "natural" order for (ASCII) strings, arrays of chars, where e.g. "abc" > "abb" and "abca" > "abc" but "abc" > "abbd", we can similarly compare any arrays (provided their elements' set is ordered) e.g. [| 10; 20; 30 |] > [| 10; 20; 29 |] and [| 10; 20; 30; -100 |] > [| 10; 20; 30 |] but [| 10; 20; 30 |] > [| 10; 20; 29; 100 |], etc... *(I have to break down my other comments into a few smaller subsections due to the comments size limit)*.

Comment: 2- ... In fact, `let comparearr<'a when 'a : comparison> (arr1 : 'a[]) (arr2 : 'a[]) : int = compare arr1 arr2` will work for  int[] and other similar types of array; e.g. `comparearr [|10;20;30|] [|10;20;29|]` will return 1, and `comparearr [|10;20;30|] [|10;20;29;-100|]` will return -1 (but note that F# follows a different order relationship than the one I suggested above).

Comment: 3- ... My issue is that I need a function without type parameter (the signature has to remain `let tycompare (o1 : obj) (o2 : obj) : int option` as above), and I am not sure how to extend your solution, which works for objects where IComparable is implemented directly, to these array cases.

Comment: @Janthelme This is an excellent problem statement. I feel it deserves its own question. Could you? Presently your original question is a good fit for this type of single inference.

Comment: @Asti. Ok. I'll accept your answer for this post and will post another question.