# F# Compare function associated to arrays

Tags: f#, icomparable

This post is related to a [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025923/comparing-two-objects-with-default-icomparable-implementation-with-f-reflection).

I believe that F# stores, somewhere, a method allowing to compare arrays of the same type, provided that the arrays' elements are comparable. The reason why I believe so : the Set type requires its elements to be comparable, and Set accepts arrays of comparable types (it even orders their elements when instantiated, allowing us to guess the comparison function it uses for arrays). A few examples :

```
let s1 = [| [| 10; 20 |]; [| 10; 19 |]; [| 10; 19; 100 |]; [| 10; 20; -100 |] |] |> Set.ofArray;;
```

returns

```
val s1 : Set<int []> =  set [[|10; 19|]; [|10; 20|]; [|10; 19; 100|]; [|10; 20; -100|]]
```

similarly,

```
let s2 = [| [| ("b", 1); ("a", 2) |]; [| ("z", 1) |]; [| ("a", 0); ("a", 0); ("a", 0) |]; [| ("b", 1); ("a", 3) |] |] |> Set.ofArray;;
```

returns

```
val s2 : Set<(string * int) []> = set [[|("z", 1)|]; [|("b", 1); ("a", 2)|]; [|("b", 1); ("a", 3)|]; [|("a", 0); ("a", 0); ("a", 0)|]]
```

(the comparison seems to be left to right element by element comparison if two arrays have the same length, or arr1 > arr2 if arr1.Length > arr2.Length)

Last, more convoluted, example :

```
type Foo = Z of int | A of int
let s3 = [| [| Z 1; A 1|]; [| A 100 |]; [| Z 1; Z 20|]; [| Z 0; Z 0; Z 0 |]; [| Z 1; Z 10|] |] |> Set.ofArray;;
```

returns

```
val s3 : Set<Foo []> = set [[|A 100|]; [|Z 1; Z 10|]; [|Z 1; Z 20|]; [|Z 1; A 1|]; [|Z 0; Z 0; Z 0|]]`
```

However the last example does not work, since objects aren't comparable:

```
let s0 = [| [| box 10; box 20 |]; [| box 10; box 19 |] |] |> Set.ofArray;;
```

returns

```
stdin(52,62): error FS0001: The type 'obj' does not support the 'comparison' constraint. For example, it does not support the 'System.IComparable' interface`
```

So I hope the above shows that Set knows how to compare arrays (provided that their elements' type is comparable).

Unfortunately I am not able to access the compare method of two arrays directly :

```
let x1 : int[] = [| 1 |]
let x2 : int[] = [| 2 |]
let c12 = x1.CompareTo(x2);;
```

Gives the following error message :

```
 let c12 = x1.CompareTo(x2);;
 -------------^^^^^^^^^
stdin(3,14): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'CompareTo' is not defined.
```

My question : how to access the CompareTo method associated to an array object? ... If possible via a function signature `arrcompare : arr1:obj -> arr2:obj -> int`  or `arrcompare : arr1:obj -> arr2:obj -> int option` (using `option` for when the 2 arguments are not arrays or not arrays of the same type).

Comment: Ack.  *Formatting.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Should be better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers of Asti and Kaefer, I was able to dig a little further and realized that what I needed was structural equality, which can be coded that way :

```
let rec structcompare (o1 : obj) (o2:obj) : int option = 
    match (o1, o2) with
    | (:? IStructuralComparable as arr1), (:? IStructuralComparable as arr2) -> 
           if arr1.GetType() = arr2.GetType() then compare arr1 arr2 |> Some else None
    | _ -> None
```

with the following results :

```
structcompare (box [| 10; 19 |]) (box [| 10; 20 |]);;
```

returns `val it : int option = Some -1`

```
structcompare (box [| 10; 19; 0 |]) (box [| 10; 20 |]);;
```

returns `val it : int option = Some 1`

and

```
structcompare (box [| 1 |]) (box [| "a" |]);;
```

returns `val it : int option = None`

Comment: This would work for arrays and tuples, but not for `List<T>` and other collection types.

Answer (score 2):

An array does not implement `System.IComparable`, while a set does. That does not mean that arrays cannot be compared; FSharp does provide comparison for arrays in analogy to true structural comparison, comparing them by rank, length and elements.

```
[|1|] < [|2|]
// val it : bool = true
```

This behavior is described in the F# spec, under the heading [Equality, Hashing,and Comparison](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A422%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C109%2C690%2C0%5D), in pseudocode:

```
// Special types not supporting IComparable
| (:? Array as arr1), (:? Array as arr2) ->
    ... compare the arrays by rank, lengths and elements ...
```

Your problem seems to stem from trying to compare things that basically cannot be compared, because they are not of the same type. Maybe you should rethink your approach, instead of individual interface implementations for various incompatible arrays, you might create a sum type and implement `System.IComparable` on that.

Comment: Modeling a set of allowed comparisons by algebraic types is likely a good fit. +1

Answer (score 1):

Well, comparing two `IComparable`s is pretty straightforward.
The rest are collections of objects, and `IEnumerable` should account for `Array`, `IList`, `ICollection` which we likely can compare in order.

And the rest are tuples which if they don't implement `IEnumerable` are expected to implement `ITuple`.

```
let rec compareAny (o1 : obj) (o2:obj) = 
    match (o1, o2) with
    | (:? IComparable as o1), (:? IComparable as o2) 
         -> Some(compare o1 o2)
    | (:? IEnumerable as arr1), (:? IEnumerable as arr2) ->      
        Seq.zip (arr1 |> Seq.cast) (arr2 |> Seq.cast)
        |> Seq.choose(fun (a, b) -> compareAny a b)
        |> Seq.skipWhile ((=) 0)
        |> Seq.tryHead
        |> Option.defaultValue 0
        |> Some
    | (:? ITuple as tup1), (:? ITuple as tup2) ->
        let tupleToSeq (tuple: ITuple) = 
            seq { for i in 0..tuple.Length do yield tuple.[i] }
        compareAny (tupleToSeq tup1) (tupleToSeq tup2)
    | _ -> None
```

An explanation of the `IEnumerable` compare is as follows:

Take elements from both |
If neither are comparable, skip, otherwise compare |
ignore all successful tests for equality |
find the first element for which comparison is `<` or `>` | if there's none (eg., an empty list, return 0) | wrap as Some.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the equality operator: `(=)`