# Checking if an F# generic parameter has an equality or comparison constraint

Tags: .net, reflection, f#

Is it possible to determine at run-time if a generic parameter to a `Type` has one of the special F# constraints of `equality` or `comparison`? These constraints are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints).

As a concrete example, given `type X<'y when 'y: equality> = { Y: 'y }`, how would I determine that `'y` has the `equality` constraint in `typedefof<X<_>>`?

I've tried using a few of the reflection APIs like [`Type.GetGenericParameterConstraints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenericparameterconstraints?view=net-6.0) and [`Type.GenericParameterAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.genericparameterattributes?view=net-6.0) but both are empty.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329454/f-type-constraints-and-reflection) mentions that the F# PowerPack can be used like so:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata

let setEntity = FSharpAssembly.FSharpLibrary.GetEntity("Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpSet`1")
for typeArg in setEntity.GenericParameters do
  printfn "%s - comparison=%b" 
    typeArg.Name 
    (typeArg.Constraints |> Seq.exists (fun c -> c.IsComparisonConstraint))
```

However, this library does not appear to support .NET core and has since been split up and can now be found [here](https://github.com/fsprojects/zzarchive-powerpack). The GitHub page mentions that "F# metadata reader is replaced by FSharp.Compiler.Service", but on a brief examination of `FSharp.Compiler.Service` this API appears to be much more complex to set up and use than the example above.

Is there a simple way to access these special constraints in F# 6 / .NET 6 using the reflection API or using some other metadata reader?

Currently I'm working around the issue by manually annotating the
parameter using an attribute:

```
[<AttributeUsage(validOn = AttributeTargets.GenericParameter, AllowMultiple = false)>]
type ConstraintAttribute([<ParamArray>] constraints: string []) =
    inherit Attribute()
    member _.Constraints = constraints |> List.ofArray

type X<[<Constraint("equality")>] 'y when 'y: equality> = { Y: 'y }

typedefof<X<_>>.GetGenericArguments().[0].GetCustomAttributes<ConstraintAttribute>()
```

Obviously having to manually annotate is not ideal, though!

Comment: Why it's necessary to know whether generic types supports equality? According to [F# spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf) 5.2.10, all types satisfy this constraint with exception of types annotated `NoEquality` or having `NoEquality` type as its member

Comment: Great question. It's because we're using reflection to generate F# source code for serialisation. In order to generate F# encoding/decoding functions for types with constrained generic parameters we need to be able to determine these constraints using reflection. Obviously using reflection for this purpose is not a perfect match - the F# compiler service would allow for more flexibility - but it was a simpler option for our team.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than pull in the whole `FSharp.Compiler.Service` package, I think it is easier to re-implement the logic defined in [the spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf):

> The constraint `type : comparison` is a comparison constraint. Such a
> constraint is met if all the following conditions hold:
>
> - If the type is a named type, then the type definition does not have, and is not inferred to have,
>   the `NoComparison` attribute, and the type definition implements `System.IComparable` or is an
>   array type or is `System.IntPtr` or is `System.UIntPtr`.
> - If the type has comparison dependencies `ty1`, ..., `tyn`, then each of these must satisfy `tyi : comparison`

This code works for the test cases below, and I think it would be fairly easy to tweak if more edge cases are discovered.

```ml
open System
open FSharp.Reflection

let comparisonDeps (t : Type) =
  seq {
    if FSharpType.IsTuple t then
      yield! FSharpType.GetTupleElements t

    elif FSharpType.IsUnion t then
      for uci in FSharpType.GetUnionCases(t, true) do
        for f in uci.GetFields() do
          f.PropertyType

    elif FSharpType.IsRecord t then
      for rf in FSharpType.GetRecordFields t do
        rf.PropertyType
  }

let isComparisonType (t : Type) =
  let seen = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<Type>()

  let rec loop t =
    seen.Add(t) |> ignore
    (
      t = typeof<IntPtr>
    )
    || (
      t = typeof<UIntPtr>
    )
    || (
      t.IsArray
    )
    || (
      (
        t.GetInterfaces()
        |> Seq.contains typeof<System.IComparable>
      )
      && (
        comparisonDeps t
        |> Seq.filter (fun t -> not (seen.Contains(t)))
        |> Seq.forall loop
      )
    )

  loop t




#r "nuget: Expecto, 9.0.4"

open Expecto

let makeTest candidate expected =
  let t = candidate.GetType()

  let message =
    if expected then
      $"%A{candidate} is a comparison type"
    else
      $"%A{candidate} is not a comparison type"

  test $"%s{t.Name} (e.g. %A{candidate})" {
    let actual = isComparisonType t

    Expect.equal actual expected message
  }

type Foo<'t> =
  {
    Foo : 't
  }

[<NoComparison>]
type Bar<'t> =
  {
    Bar : 't
  }

[<NoComparison>]
type Qux =
  {
    Qux : int
  }

type Baz =
  {
    Baz : Qux
  }

let tests =
  testList "isComparisonType" [
    makeTest 123 true
    makeTest "abc" true
    makeTest [ 1; 2; 3 ] true
    makeTest (1, "a") true
    makeTest (Set.ofSeq [ 1; 2; 3 ]) true
    makeTest { Foo = 123 } true
    makeTest (Some { Foo = 123 }) true
    makeTest { Foo = fun x -> x + 1 } false
    makeTest { Bar = "abc" } false
    makeTest [ { Bar = 7 } ] false
    makeTest { Foo = { Bar = "abc" } } false
    makeTest { Qux = 2 } false
    makeTest (true, { Qux = 2 }) false
    makeTest (Map.ofSeq [ 1, { Qux = 2 } ]) true
    makeTest (Some { Qux = 2 }) false
    makeTest { Baz = { Qux = 2 } } false
    makeTest [| true; false |] true
    makeTest (IntPtr 1) true
    makeTest [| IntPtr 1; IntPtr 2; IntPtr 3 |] true
    makeTest (UIntPtr 42u) true
  ]

let args = fsi.CommandLineArgs |> Array.skip 1

runTestsWithCLIArgs [] args tests
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @sdgfsdh - it works perfectly for closed constructed types as you have perfectly demonstrated. Really appreciate it! As noted in the question, the issue is I need it to work for type definitions. So more like: `type WithComparison<'y when 'y: comparison> = { Y: 'y }`; `type WithoutComparison<'y> = { Y: 'y }`; `makeTest (typedefof<WithComparison<_>>) true`; `makeTest (typedefof<WithoutComparison<_>>) false`. Unfortunately these do not work. In both cases the outer record reports implementing `IComparable`, and the type parameter `y` does not, yielding `false`. Any ideas?